# Typescript papaparse No overload matches this call

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, papaparse

I use [Papaparse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/papaparse) lib in typescript.

```
import Papa from 'papaparse';

Papa.parse(filePath, {
  download: true, 
  header: true,
  dynamicTyping: true,
  skipEmptyLines: true,
};
```

`filepath` type is `string`

I get error on filePath:

```
No overload matches this call. The last overload generated the following error. The 'string' type argument is not assignable to the 'unique symbol' type parameter.
```

In [@types/papaparse](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/papaparse), there is

```
/**
 * Parse local files
 * @param file a File object obtained from the DOM.
 * @param config a config object which contains a callback.
 * @returns Doesn't return anything. Results are provided asynchronously to a callback function.
 */
// tslint:disable-next-line: no-unnecessary-generics
export function parse<T, TFile extends LocalFile = LocalFile>(file: TFile, config: ParseLocalConfig<T, TFile>): void;

/**
 * Parse remote files
 * @param url the path or URL to the file to download.
 * @param config a config object.
 * @returns Doesn't return anything. Results are provided asynchronously to a callback function.
 */
// tslint:disable-next-line: no-unnecessary-generics
export function parse<T>(url: string, config: ParseRemoteConfig<T>): void;
```

Comment: This import form...`import Papa from 'papaparse';` is used to import `default` exports. Why don't you try `import { parse } from 'papaparse';` and then use the function directly?

Comment: I have the impression that you are missing the function `complete(results: ParseResult<T>, file: TInput): void` from the `config` argument. This may be confusing the compiler to call a different overload than the one you think you are calling.

Comment: i updated the body question. i still get errors

Answer (score 6):

I added `complete` function and updated my code like this:

```
import { parse, ParseResult } from 'papaparse';

parse(filePath, {
  download: true, 
  header: true,
  dynamicTyping: true,
  skipEmptyLines: true,
  complete: function (results: ParseResult<Record<string, unknown>>) {
    /* ...code stuff... */
  }
};
```

and it works. thx

Comment: Thanks, looks like the `ParseResult` is the key here.